# PHP deleting a row with a string

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to delete a row that matches a string that is passed in to the method.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$data = array($_POST["username"]);


$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM Table WHERE username = username=? ");
$stmt->execute($data);
```

I tried a few combinations of the SQL statement but cannot get one to work

Answer (score 1):

```
// Store user input in a variable
$data =  $_POST["username"];

// Prepare the query
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM Table WHERE username=:username");

// Bind the value
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Execute the query
$success = $stmt->execute();

// If query succeeded, display the number of affected rows
if ($success) {
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $affected_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spot the SQL error:

`username = username=?`

Should be

`username = ?`